# Métodos para mudança de orientação do Framework UI Automator não funcionam

Tags: android, kotlin, android-uiautomator

Os métodos **setOrientationLeft()** e **setOrientationRight()** abaixo simplesmente não funcionam, tanto em dispositivos emulados quanto em dispositivos físicos. Gostaria de saber se existem regras para usá-lós ou cenários específicos.

**ExampleInstrumentedTestKotlin.kt**

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
    @SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 16)
    @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

    class ExampleInstrumentedTestKotlin {

        private var mDevice: UiDevice? = null

        private val launcherPackageName: String
            get() {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
                val pm = getApplicationContext<Context>().packageManager
                val resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
                return resolveInfo!!.activityInfo.packageName
            }

        companion object {
            private val BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE = "xxx.xxxx.xxxx"
            private val LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = 5000
            private val STRING_TO_BE_TYPED = "UiAutomator"
        }

        @Before
        fun openApp() {

            mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
            mDevice!!.pressHome()

            val launcherPackage = launcherPackageName
            assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue())
                    mDevice!!.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT.toLong())

            val context = getApplicationContext<Context>()
            val intent = context.packageManager
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE)
            intent!!.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            context.startActivity(intent)
            mDevice!!.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT.toLong())

        }

        @Test
        fun teste(){
            load(10)  //função para aguardar 10 segundos
            mDevice!!.setOrientationLeft()
            load(10)  //função para aguardar 10 segundos
            mDevice!!.setOrientationRight()
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que não está indo?? qual erro aparece? UiDevice é nulo sempre mesmo?

Comment: O código não apresenta nenhum erro, ele passa como se tivesse tudo ok, porém a orientação do dispositivo não muda como expresso na documentação, a parte do código que faltava eu adicionei, era a função openApp.

Comment: Já experimentou usar algum método `wait` do `UiDevice`? Por exemplo, [`waitForIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#waitforidle_1)

Comment: sim, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O "problema" foi solucionado, na versão anterior do aplicativo ele só funcionava no modo **portrait**, para manter o visual do aplicativo interessante, então tinha a regra nas activitys no manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Na versão atual essa regra foi removida das minhas activity e então os métodos agora funcionam normal, tanto em dispositivos emulados quanto em dispositivos físico.

Resumindo, os métodos funcionam sim, desde que a orientação das acitivtys não estejam configuradas para funcionarem em um modo especifico.